# Full expression for findall

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a regular expression that looks for a url in some text like:

```
my_urlfinder = re.compile(r'\shttp:\/\/(\S+.|)blah.com/users/(\d+)(\/|)')
text = "blah blah http://blah.com/users/123 blah blah http://blah.com/users/353"

for match in my_urlfinder.findall(text):
    print match  #prints an array with all the individual parts of the regex
```

How do I get the entire url? Currently match just prints out the matched parts (which I need for other things)...but I also want the full url.

Comment: The easiest would be to add an extra set of parentheses, enclosing the entire regexp. Then you get it along with the parts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to not using any capturing groups would be to add another one around everything:

```
my_urlfinder = re.compile(r'\s(http:\/\/(\S+.|)blah.com/users/(\d+)(\/|))')
```

This will allow you to keep the inner capturing groups while still having the whole result.

For the demo text it would yield these results:

```
('http://blah.com/users/123', '', '123', '')
('http://blah.com/users/353', '', '353', '')
```

As a side note beware that the current expression requires a whitespace *in front* of the URL, so if the text started with one that would not be matched.

Answer (score 2):

You should make your groups non-capturing:

```
my_urlfinder = re.compile(r'\shttp:\/\/(?:\S+.|)blah.com/users/(?:\d+)(?:\/|)')
```

`findall()` *changes behaviour* when there are capturing groups. With groups, it'll only return the groups, without capturing groups, the whole matched text is returned instead.

Demo:

```
>>> text = "blah blah http://blah.com/users/123 blah blah http://blah.com/users/353"
>>> my_urlfinder = re.compile(r'\shttp:\/\/(?:\S+.|)blah.com/users/(?:\d+)(?:\/|)')
>>> for match in my_urlfinder.findall(text):
...     print match
... 
 http://blah.com/users/123
 http://blah.com/users/353
```